# passing text from python to shell | unicode | applying cut on it

Tags: python, shell, unicode, awk, cut

I have a python script that essentially parses an xml file, uses the package `re` and prints text as follows:

```
string = str(search_compiled.groups(0)[0].encode('utf-8')) + "%" + str(text.encode('utf-8'))
print string
```

I receive the text in the shell script as follows:

```
string="$($file.py $arg1 $arg2 $arg3)"
varA="$(echo "$string" | cut -d'%' -f1)"
varB="$(echo "$string" | cut -d'%' -f2)"
echo "$string"
```

So, in summary, I need the passed string to be cut into two by the delimiter '%' and store the results in `varA` and `varB`.

**The splitting does not happen.**
string shows the entire thingy: part A plus the part B. Here's the catch, the '%' I added in the python script does not get printed though.

Could anyone please help me in understanding what is going wrong?

Comment: What error do you get? What is the output of `file.py`?

Comment: Putting the name of your script in a variable `file` seems extremely odd.

Comment: You do know that the traditional Python 2 print formatting functions using `%` require the character `%` to be doubled in the format string in order to print a literal `%`?

Comment: Does `file.py` print out anything besides ASCII? I guess it may since you are encoding to `utf-8`.

Comment: @tripleee Used the file.py for this example purpose. Of course the real file name's different. Also, Yes, I do know that. The thing is, even if I use '$' instead of '%', the issue doesn't get solved.

Comment: @davejagoda Yes, it does. At least it gives me an error if I don't use the `encode('utf-8')` part.

Comment: I think we need to see your Python script, or representative sample output.  `python -c 'print(u"Fn\u00F6rd%foo".encode("utf-8"))'` might be sufficient to make your question self-contained.  If not, find an example which is.

Comment: @davejagoda `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2265' in position 243: ordinal not in range(128)` Here's the error.

Comment: @HobbitEesmereldatGoldworthy see my answer below - works for me in an example I've created.

Comment: What do `print(type(search_compiled.groups(0)[0]))`  and `print(type(text))` show if you include that right before the assignment line `string = str()`?

Comment: @HobbitEesmereldatGoldworthy did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pipe and cut commands as you have in the question but without the quotes on the delimiter character use -d% instead of -d'%'

```
varA=$(echo $string | cut -f1 -d%)  
varB=$(echo $string | cut -f2 -d%)
```

Comment: @jasv Hi. Thanks for the links. But it's not working as expected. Like in python, we have `split('%', 1)` to split on just the first occurrence. Is there anything like it here?

Comment: I apologize for code errors. Just learning rules/etc for stackoverflow.

Comment: your code example has the delimiter with '%' and mine is just using the % without the quotes. I tested it and it worked for a string with % in the middle.

Comment: @jasv Sorry. Doesn't work. I'm positive this is an encoding issue. Because the commands in isolation work, but with the string from the python output doesn't.

Comment: The proper solution is still `varA=${string#*%}; varB=${string%%%*}` -- if you insist on `echo`, you should put double quotes around the argument; `echo "$string"`.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read this for a 3rd time, and I think this is the basic problem (from your description):

**string shows the entire thingy: part A plus the part B. Here's the catch, the '%' I added in the python script does not get printed though.**

The conversion of data to utf-8 then back to string seems suspect to me. Can you change the string creation line in your python program to this:

```
string = u'{}%{}'.format(search_compiled.groups(0)[0].encode('utf-8'), text.encode('utf-8'))
```

You might be double encoding, so this could be what you need:

```
string = u'{}%{}'.format(search_compiled.groups(0)[0], text)
```

Add this in the shell script before it calls the python script:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Gives no error. But cut doesn't split.

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@test /tmp]$ eval `echo "aaa%bbb%ccc" | awk -F '%' '{print "a="$1" b="$2}'`
[root@test /tmp]$ echo $a
aaa
[root@test /tmp]$ echo $b
bbb
```

**Explanation**

Use `awk -F '%' '{print "a="$1" b="$2}'` get like this `a=aaa b=bbb`

eval `a=aaa b=bbb` Equivalent to the input terminal

```
$ a=aaa
$ b=bbb
```

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your methods (where applicable) elsewhere. Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827) and liable to be deleted. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10301047)

Comment: Sorry! I can't use English explain.

Comment: Even if you write it in your own language and Google translate it into broken English, it's better than nothing.